# Flutter WebView within ListView or CustomScrollView - Crashes on Android for large heights

Tags: android, flutter, webview, crash

Currently we've got a problem with the Flutter WebView within a ScrollView. We would like to display a WebView with article content written in HTML below an Image and other content like the title or buttons. It shouldn't be possible to just scroll the WebView. Instead, the entire content should be scrolled together.

The problem is, that the WebView should scroll together with the header. Therefore the WebView needs a fixed height as far as I know. Via Javascript it's possible to get the scroll height of the WebView. This is great working on iOS, but on Android the App is crashing when the height of the WebView is too large. The reason for this seems to be that under Android the height of the WebView may only be as large as the screen. Otherwise there is a warning message:

> Creating a virtual display of size: [1080, 11303] may result in
> problems(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2897).It is larger
> than the device screen size: [1080, 1794].

Is there a better possibility to use a WebView inside a ListView? We also tried [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html), but on some articles we also need JavaScript and this is not supported. On large pages it's also a bit laggy.

This is an example App of the current problem. It works for small pages, but not for large ones. The height when it crashes depends on the device. You could for example set the height manually to a value like 13000:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: CrashingWebViewExample()));

class CrashingWebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CrashingWebViewExampleState createState() => _CrashingWebViewExampleState();
}

class _CrashingWebViewExampleState extends State<CrashingWebViewExample> {
  WebViewController _webViewController;
  double _webViewHeight = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
          Container(
            height: _webViewHeight,
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_size',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onPageFinished: (String url) => _onPageFinished(context, url),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                _webViewController = controller;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.yellow),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onPageFinished(BuildContext context, String url) async {
    double newHeight = double.parse(
      await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"),
    );
    setState(() {
      _webViewHeight = newHeight;
    });
  }
}
```

The code is also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/DFelten/flutter_webview_in_scrollview).

There is now also [a ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62784) for this issue in the flutter repository.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still persist:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34138

Not so perfect workaround:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
          Container(
            height: 500, // or any other height
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 150 // need to leave blank space on sides so the whole screen could be scrollable
            child: WebView(
              // this makes inside of webView scrollable
              gestureRecognizers: Set()..add(Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())),
              initialUrl: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_size',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            ),
          ),
          Container(height: 100, color: Colors.yellow),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```